# extracting data from google spreadsheet into a html table

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet that stores data at my work and is constantly being updated via google drive so it is always online editing, what I want to do is to be able to extract the values in those cells and have them show up in a HTML5 table on my website, what would be the best solution for this?

I did try one way which was to just embed the spreadsheet in a iFrame and have that refresh every 5 minutes, but the refresh loading is too slow and it causes issues with trying to get the spreadsheet to fit perfectly in the iframe everytime I refresh. these websites will be on display on TV screens so I dont want to be adjusting them regularly, they will auto refresh and be idle.

Comment: You can try and fetch the info from the sheet as json: https://developers.google.com/gdata/samples/spreadsheet_sample once you get it - it will be easy to embed it in your website.

Answer (score 3):

Your Google Sheet's rows/columns can be exported as a pretty minimal HTML table.  You can grab that HTML and manipulate it however you like.  Here's how to get it:

1. Open the Sheet and find your **file_id** in the URL, and the **gid** for the specific tab you wish to export (you may have several spreadsheets within a single Google Sheet).
2. Use this URL string, replacing **`<FILE_ID>`** and **`<TAB_GID>`** with your own:

   - `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<FILE_ID>/gviz/tq?tqx=out:html&tq&gid=<TAB_GID>`

You can set the refresh/recalculation rate under **File > Spreadsheet settings** to be every minute, if necessary.

**Example:**

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit#gid=0) is a Google Sheet with some data.  To export this as an HTML table, we take:

- the **file_id**: `1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms` and
- the **tab_gid**: `0`

from the URL and substitute those into the URL string (above), yielding:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/gviz/tq?tqx=out:html&tq&gid=0

Hope that helps.

Comment: Can you explain where you found the documentation for the URL you composed for simple HTML table export? Looks close to what I'm looking for, but I want to follow up with it. E.g. what does all that `tq` mean?

Comment: You save me a lot of time! Thank you :)